# ASP.NET Identity Custom PasswordValidator check against Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I want to add a check that the password doesn't contain the username in ASP.NET Identity framework.

An implementation of a Custom PasswordValidator should do the job fine, but how can I access the username?

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator : PasswordValidator
{
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(string password)
    {
        var result = await base.ValidateAsync(password);

        //How to access username here

        return result;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is the user logged in at this point, or is this for new users? If the latter, it may not be possible, as `User.Identity` won't be set until user has logged in.

Comment: @stuartd: The UserManager will validate the password using the same PasswordValidator while creating a user, or changing the password for an existing user

Comment: Any joy? @Niko Did you figure this out?

Comment: No,I have no solution to solve this in a correct way @ChrisMoutray

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Fluent Validation library](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

It has a predicate validator (Must) that is perfect for your scenario.
So your validation rule will look like:

```
    RuleFor(model => model.Password)
        .Must((model, username) => !model.Password.Contains(username))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the goal was to **not** put this validation in the model. I want to centralize this check in the Usermanager with all the other password and user requirements.